# Exclude directory from https

Tags: http, https, apache2

I have a Server with a redirect to https.
At home I have several IP-Cameras, which create a website without https.
I wanted to look at several cameras at once, so I created a really simple html-script with 6 iframes in it. I saved it in my server.
Now I can't have a look at my cameras, because it is not possible to embed a http-site on a https-site. I really don't want to set up a server at home, so I tried to exclude the site from the https-redirect, but it did not work.

I tried to open /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and edited:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
# ServerName www.example.de
Redirect / https://www.example.de/

ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

# Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
# error, crit, alert, emerg.
# It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
# modules, e.g.
#LogLevel info ssl:warn

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.de
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} !=www.example.de/kameras/
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

I've tried

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/kameras/
```

which didn't work either.

Has anyone an idea, how to exclude the whole directory kameras from https?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Every script on my server requires identification.php.

So I added just the following code in this identification.php:

```
$httpsactive = false;
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])){
    if (strtoupper($_SERVER['HTTPS'])=='ON'){
        $httpsactive=true;
    }
}
if(!$httpsactive){
    header('location: https://www.hagen-russisch.de'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    exit;
}
```

After that I cleared the apache conf file. Now any script, which does not require the identification.php is accesible by https and http.